# How to advance a loop to select and copy data from column A?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to split raw data in column A into two strings then copy the first string into column B and the second into C, move to the next row down of A and repeat.

I'm trying to advance the loop to the next row using several integers (Row, Check, x and y) but they do not increase past 0.

I have tried adding to the integers in their own dedicated lines (basically trying to get a line that is "Row + 1").

```
Dim x As Integer 'Row value
Dim y As Integer 'Column Value
Dim Row As Integer 'Row value used only in the check
Dim raw As String 'Raw imported data
Dim ValueArray() As String 'Array for attributes and values

Do While Check <> " " 'While the Check value isn't nothing,
    Check = Cells(Row + 1, 1) 'Check for data in the current row of the A column
    raw = Cells(x + 1, 1).Value 'The raw data is the row + 1 of A column
    ValueArray = Split(raw, "=>") 'Spilt the raw into an attribute and a value 
                                  'then save in an array
    ActiveSheet.Cells(y + 1, 2).Value = ValueArray(0) 'The value of the next row 
                                                      'in the B column is the 
                                                      'first value in the array
    ActiveSheet.Cells(y + 1, 3).Value = ValueArray(1) 'The value of the next row 
                                                      'in the C column is the 
                                                      'second value in the array
Loop 'Continue the loop
```

There would be a value like **Contact => John Smith** and the code is supposed to separate the attribute (First part) from the value (Second part). The attribute is supposed to be placed in column B and the value in C.

The loop is then supposed to start again but now that the integers have all increased by 1, it should process the next row in column A. It instead loops continuously through the first row and crashes Excel.

Comment: Reason for your counter not being incremented is because you haven't specifically increment your counter. You will need a line like: `Row = Row + 1`. Also, I would strongly recommend not to use excel reserved words as your vairbales (i.e. `Row`). Using them can cause errors which at times are very difficult to track

Comment: Note that `Check <> " "` doesn't test for an empty cell but for a space character in a cell! If you want to check for an empty string you must use `Check <> ""` or `Check <> vbNullString`. Also in the first run of the loop `Check` is not initialized yet (undeclared empty variable). So the code you show should never run the loop at all.

Comment: This is great! I have changed Row to curRow to avoid errors and included "curRow = curRow + 1" and this integer now increases. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusted VBA code:

- added `Len(raw)` check instead of `Check <> " "`
- added `lngCount` which will increase by 1 with every successful loop

```vb
    Dim raw As String 'Raw imported data
    Dim ValueArray() As String 'Array for attributes and values
    Dim lngCount As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        raw = .Cells(1, 1).Value
        Do While Len(raw)
            ValueArray = Split(raw, "=>")
            If UBound(ValueArray) > 0 Then
                .Cells(1 + lngCount, 2).Value = ValueArray(0)
                .Cells(1 + lngCount, 3).Value = ValueArray(1)
            End If
            lngCount = lngCount + 1
            raw = .Cells(1, 1).Offset(lngCount, 0).Value
        Loop 'Continue the loop
    End With
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Note you should check `If UBound(ValueArray) > 0` before using `ValueArray(1)` or it will fail on cells that do not contain `=>`.

Comment: No problem at all @LucaJordan. Feel free to upvote all useful answers and accept the correct answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Would be a good idea to replace `ActiveSheet` with a fully qualified sheet as activesheet might not always be the sheet you wan to work with

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with a simple formula. No need for VBA here:

- Column B (Attribute):
  `=TRIM(LEFT(A:A,FIND("=>",A:A)-1))`
- Column C (Value):
  `=TRIM(RIGHT(A:A,LEN(A:A)-FIND("=>",A:A)-1))`

[image]

Comment: Is this able to work in newly generated sheets? I probably should have said but forgot, but the importing code I have generates a new sheet based on how many files are in a selected folder. (I would post that code but it is un-formatted and basically illegible right now) Is there anyway I could (vba or otherwise) get this formula onto the brand new sheet automatically?

Comment: @LucaJordan You can write a formula to a range like `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B10").Formula = "=TRIM(LEFT(A:A,FIND(""=>"",A:A)-1))"`. Note that quotes in the formula itself need to be doubled.

Comment: This is a much better solution than using VBA

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `VBA` to do this you might find it easier using a `For` Loop and a single `Index` for all of your columns

```
Dim RowIndex As Long ' Row value used only in the check
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim raw As String ' Raw imported data
Dim ValueArray() As String ' Array for attributes and values

With ActiveSheet
    RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' Get last row in Column A

    For RowIndex = 1 To RowCount
        raw = Cells(RowIndex, 1).Value2 ' The raw data is the row + 1 of A column
        ValueArray = Split(raw, "=>")
        .Cells(RowIndex, 2).Value2 = WorksheetFunction.Trim(ValueArray(0)) ' The value of the next row
                                                                           ' in the B column is the
                                                                           ' first value in the array
        .Cells(RowIndex, 3).Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(ValueArray(1)) ' The value of the next row
                                                                          ' in the C column is the
                                                                          ' second value in the array
    Next RowIndex
End With
```

I've also used `Worksheetfunction.Trim` to remove and leading or trailing whitespace and any double spacing in the string